# Record many-to-many relationships Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-8

I have these 2 tables that are related to Many to Mutos, and a pivor table between them, I'm recording normally this way, but I don't know how to make the relationship between the values.

Each bank records 7 records, which are 7 days a week, and each day has its opening and closing hours.

How do I make this relationship automatic?

```
public function createShop()
    {
        $schedules = [
            ['start' => now(),'end' => now()],
            ['start' => now(),'end' => now()],
            ['start' => now(),'end' => now()],
            ['start' => now(),'end' => now()],
            ['start' => now(),'end' => now()],
            ['start' => now(),'end' => now()],
            ['start' => now(),'end' => now()],
        ];

        $daysweeks = [
            ['name' => 'Segunda-Feira'],
            ['name' => 'Terça-Feira'],
            ['name' => 'Quarta-Feira'],
            ['name' => 'Quinta-Feira'],
            ['name' => 'Sexta-Feira'],
            ['name' => 'Sábado'],
            ['name' => 'Domingo'],
        ];

        $schedule = Schedules::insert($schedules);
        $daysweek = DaysWeek::insert($daysweeks);

        $daysweek->schedule()->sync($schedule);

    }
```

[image: print]

Comment: Define automatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So was my code for the problem in question

```
foreach ($daysweeks as $daysweek) {

            $getShopDaySchedule = ShopDaySchedule::create([
                'shop_id' => $selectShop->id,
                'enable' => 0
            ]);

            $getDay = $getShopDaySchedule->daysWeeks()->create($daysweek);

            $getDay->allSchedules()->create($schedules);

        }
```